# Launch console application before user login

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application, scheduled-tasks, startup

I have a C# console application, which interacts with a SQL Server Database, and I want to configure it to launch at system startup and before user login. My application is an infinite loop that reads/writes data from/to database (after processing), and writes log messages to the console window.

I tried windows task scheduler. The application launches, but I had two problems:

1. The app can't access the database (Error message: " Cannot open database "MyDataBase" requested by the login. The login failed." extracted from a log file )
2. When I log in to windows, I can't retrieve the app console, and it doesn't figure in the task manager's process list.

I don't really know if this issue has a solution (or maybe a workaround) in windows, but I really need it because the server is in a distant location, and we suffer from power cut-offs in that area, so I have to check it periodically and launch my app each time the cut-off occurs.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you considered running as a windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the right thing to do here is to use two programs.  First, a windows service that starts on boot and restarts whenever it fails. This service likely will need to either connect with SQL server credentials (not Windows credentials) OR run under a service ID that has access to the database.  The second program would start on user login and would read/display any log messages from the windows service.  Essentially it would function like "tail" on the log file written by the service, though you could come up with a more sophisticated logger registration process so that it could receive messages directly from the service if you desire.

Comment: Thanks for help. It seems it's the only solution for my case here. In fact, I opted for dividing my application into two pieces: one which is the Windows Service. It starts even before any user logs in, but I needed to add a dependency to MSSQLSERVER in order to be able to access SQL Server Database . The windows service simply creates a new process which launches my console application, and logs the changes using log4Net library ([link](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/)) which has the UDP Appender, that logs messages using UDP network messages sent over IP using a specified port

Comment: the second part is a GUI (winforms) application, where I added a UDP listener which receives UDP messages from the same port used by the windows Service (I used 8081 for both). Then, it logs the messages to the user interface. In order to separate the listener from the user interface, and avoid UI freezing, I used the SynchronizationContext class to launch a thread (the listener) which reports back to the UI every time it receives a new message.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to refactor your app to become a Windows Service.  You'll have to live with the fact that you can't "access" the app itself directly.  Typically, you'd create a companion app that can manage the service.  Think of the services that you're familiar with on Windows... IIS, SQL Server, etc... at a high level, they all work this way.